# site.Master file does not esist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Probably a silly question, being new to development, I am following tutorials and find references to a site.Master file in many of the tutorials I have come across. Is this something that is autogenerated or must I create this file myself? I have access to vs2010 and 2012 and I don't see a `site.Master` file in any of my projects that i have started. There is however a `_layout.cshtml` file. I only ask as in every tutorial that mentions this file, doe not mention creating it, just that the file exists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the deal.

You are probably reading tutorials about MVC or MVC 2 where the view engine is aspx and master pages still are used as a template.

Since MVC 3 a new engine is introduced: [**Razor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine). Also this [**_Layout.cshtml**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) page takes the role of Site.master (master page). With Visual Studio 2010/2012 if you select an MVC project it defaults to Razor syntax and includes _Layout.cshtml as a Shared View.

You can still follow these 'old' tutorials, but mind this difference and act accordingly when recreating the steps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be auto generated if the template you created your project from included a master file. Look in the Solution Explorer (If the solution Explorer isn't visible, hit View -> Solution Explorer) and see if you have a file in your site that ends in the extension ".Master". If not, right click your project in the Solution Explorer then click Add New Item. On the left select your language (Visual Basic or C#) then in the right select Master Page. Give it a name at the bottom such as site.Master. Then click Add. You'll have a master page.

After that, you'll probably want to hook up your other pages to use the new master page. But I'll leave that to your tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Master Pages:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX

site.master files are usually auto-generated for you when you make a new default ASP.NET website in Visual Studio.  Depending on where are in your project, you may need to create one yourself, if Master Pages is the route you want to take.  They aren't mandatory, they just make things easier IMO.

Answer (score 0):

MVC has no concept of a masterpage, and site.Master doesn't exist. If you find a reference to site.Master on a tutorial you are using 'regular' ASP.NET (or, as I like to call it, if I'm trying to be polite 'old-fashioned' ASP.NET), not ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Nor did I, although I suspect it's mistagged.

Comment: @msm8bball it's probably not mistagged. He mentions the `_layout.cshtml`.

Comment: I think the OP is (understandably) confused between the difference, and has been reading ASP.net tutorials, and set up an MVC application in Visual Studio, hence the disconnect.

Comment: In ASP.Net MVC you can choose whether you like .aspx or .cshtml views. In the former you have a site.Master in the Views/Shared folder and in the later u have the _layout.cshtml to control the global layout of your application.

Comment: This is the case only with ASP.NET MVC 3 or newer.

Comment: while true, there is no compelling reason to use MVC 2 or older other than maintaining legacy applications. As the question asks about learning a new framework, choosing ASP.NET MVC 2 or MVC 1 as the next thing to learn seems odd.

Answer (score -1):

Yes , It is auto-generated when you create a new ASP Website Project in VS

Comment: It depends on the template used to create the project. So your answer could be false. I wouldn't make such a blanket statement like you just did.